# Potential difficulties in trip to Europe?

Tags: europe

Building on [this](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/43660) question. I am 18, and an Indian, and am planning to go on a month long trip to Europe (this year or the next, depending on some stuff). I plan to either go alone, or with a friend. I am good at speaking English, so language shouldn't be a problem. The answers to the linked question do provide some useful information, but I would like to know beforehand what could potentially go wrong in the trip (due to my nationality, or not being a 'western' citizen, for that matter).  The countries I will be visiting are more or less the same as in the linked question. What additional precautions, if any, would I need to take on the trip?

Additional information: 
I have a fair amount of experience in travelling, and am used to being independent. I have previously travelled to Sweden, on a student exchange program. I lived there for three weeks. Overall, I loved the atmosphere and the experience in general. I have never been to any other country in Europe before. My primary aim for the trip is to see and explore the culture, the cities, and even smaller towns, if possible, while not rushing from place to place in a hurry. My budget is pretty flexible so that shouldn't really be a problem.

Comment: Hi SaintSix_. I think this question is going to be a bit too vague for this site. Knowing nothing about you, your experience of travelling, or what you are going to do in Europe, it's very hard to give a good answer. If you had particular areas of concern it would be much better to ask specific questions about them. We are not a general advice site.

Comment: Thank you for letting me know. The question is updated accordingly, hopefully that's enough. And no, I don't have any particular areas of concern.

Comment: ' I am good at speaking English, so language shouldn't be a problem' You might have a bit of a skewed image of English capacities of Europeans if you have only been to Sweden so far. In many other places in Europe you won't find so many people fluent in English as in Sweden.

Comment: @drat oh..so what should I do? Carry a dictionary or a basic translating guide? Will translators like Google Translate help/be sufficient?

Comment: @SaintSix_ it will mainly depend on where you want to go. If you stick to more touristy spots, you should be able to get by with English only, if you plan to go to other areas I think a phrasebook or some other translation help will be good. I think Google translate should do the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You ask specifically about "*due to my nationality, or not being a 'western' citizen*". There is unlikely to be any trouble based on your nationality or appearance. Europe today is a very multicultural place, and you will find people of similar nationality or appearance in all places in Europe.

Just as anywhere, however, people of all kinds can find trouble if they are careless or overly gullible.

If you have a suitable visa (necessary for travel in the first place of course), you will not encounter any official difficulties.

Comment: It would be great if your answer was true for all of Europe, but while being Indian in (say) London is no problem at all, the OP may encounter some prejudice in (for example) the back blocks of Eastern Europe.

Comment: @jpatokal my Indian brother in law has at least once been regarded with suspicion in Sarajevo, but once the natives realized that he was Indian and not Roma/Gypsy, they no longer had any problem with him.