# Is it a bad idea for an 18 year old girl to travel alone internationally?

Tags: air-travel

I've been planning a trip to visit my boyfriend of 5 years (yes I've met him but he came here) in Europe. I'm 18 years old and my parents are fighting me on it relentlessly. I have the money and everything, but they are scared I'll be involved in a terrorist attack/get kidnapped for human trafficking. I've tried to convince her that it's not as common as she thinks, people travel solo every single day and are fine. 
How can I convince her I will be fine? Or am I wrong?
Anyone with travelling experience is especially welcome
to give their input.

Comment: Are you legally a minor? This will determine a few things.

Comment: Not only is this question purely opinion based, but also details such as which country you are going to et al is missing. Surely if you were a woman going to Azerbaijan the concern and advice might be different than from Switzerland.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Traveling in Europe Solo - 18 years old. Feasible?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/43660/traveling-in-europe-solo-18-years-old-feasible)

Comment: I think the question is okay if we know the destination.  I am voting to close as "unclear" (not "primarily opinion based," despite the banner above) in the absence of that information.  Taylor, if you edit the question to include that and any other details, I'll vote to reopen.

Comment: I started traveling with just friends at 16 and internationally at 18/19 and am very much alive.  If I were a parent, I'd actually be more concerned about the 'boyfriend' aspect.

Comment: Statistically, if you die on your journey, you will die in a car accident. And depending on where you come from and where you go, that risk could actually be smaller than if you stayed at home. Another risk is drowning if you like to go swimming in unfamiliar waters in foreign countries. The other risks you listed are negligible, unless you intend to travel to a civil war zone like eastern Ukraine, which is inadvisable. None of this is opinion based.

Comment: It absolutely depends on where you plan to go, and how dumb or careful you are behaving there. In Europe, it is very common for people even below 18 to travel alone or in groups, and there is no special risk compared to travelling with parents or travelling at 25. If you apply some common sense, it should be fine. Going to South america or asia might be different, though; I can't say.

Comment: @Johns-305 I suspect the parents are more worried about the boyfriend part (a long-distance relationship beginning at age 13!) and the dangers of travel are pretextual. Western Europe, to address the OP, is probably safer than your hometown, as long as you don't do something stupid like get black-out drunk. (At 18 you are legal to drink there.)